# Print Duplicate email and Telephone number in Scraping python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am Facing issue it print two times email and phone number along with it print tele and send to also how it trim on scraping i tried but failed.
Please help me out from this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
suit=[]
url ="https://www.allenovery.com/en-gb/global/people/Shruti-Ajitsaria"

r= requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
#time.sleep(1)
content = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'hyperlinks')
#print(content)
for property in content:
  link = property.find('a', {'class': 'tel'})['href']
  email = property.find_next('a', {'class': 'mail'})['href']  
  print(link,email)
```

Comment: There is no issue I think. The provided URL has two div with class `hyperlinks`. Therefore, calling this class would always result in two elements having the mentioned class.

Comment: I am Getting two times same records

Comment: It's not the same record. When you search `hyperlinks` in the mentioned website's elements (in the inspect mode), you get two `div` elements with this class name which shows there are two matches for your search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your code to see that how many times your loop is going to be run
`print(len(content))`

If you do so, you will find that the length of your loop (which is equal to length of `content` variable) is `2`, and as you put the `print(link,email)` inside your loop, it will run twice and you see the printed result two times... in other words, you are printing the result 2 times. to fix that, remove the indentation for `print(link,email)` to put it outside the loop and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate email and Telephone number because they exist more than once.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
suit=[]
url ="https://www.allenovery.com/en-gb/global/people/Shruti-Ajitsaria"

r= requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
#time.sleep(1)

tel = soup.select('div.hyperlinks > ul > li > a')[0].get('href')
email= soup.select('div.hyperlinks > ul > li > a')[1].get('href')
print(tel,email)
```

Output:

```
tel:+44 20 3088 1831 mailto:shruti.ajitsaria@allenovery.com
```